# How to search for nuget package versions in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to search for all nuget package versions for give nuget package, via the rest api https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/artifact-version-search however it requires a groupid, which doesn't seems to be a concept for nuget packages, and it is a required field

What should groupid be for a nuget package?

https://artifacts.xxx.yyy/artifactory/api/search/versions?a=packagename&repos=repositoryname

I would expect that you could search without a groupid, as packagename and repostoryname should be enough to identify a nuget package

Answer (score 0):

When using the search in the 'UI' do you get the expected results?

Could you share the REST API command used?

Note what is written in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46107916):

"Package search is based on standard properties that Artifactory attaches to packages according to their type. For example, when searching for NuGet packages, Artifactory is actually matching the search terms to the values for the nuget.id and nuget.version properties that should be attached to every NuGet package."

Comment: The UI search works fine without groupid, however not the rest api

This is the rest api command I used, just with scrambled parameter values 

https://artifacts.xxx.yyy/artifactory/api/search/versions?a=packagename&repos=repositoryname

The problem is, it give the error 400: The groupId and artifactId cannot be empty. 

and groupid cannot be empty or * 

it kinda seems like they implemented this only for artifacts using groupid and didn't consider other types

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [search API](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/property-search) in Artifactory to search specific properties.

For example:

```
jf rt curl -XGET "/api/search/prop?nuget.id=Azure.Core"
```

This will return a JSON list of all artifacts that has the property `nuget.id` and the corresponding value `Azure.Core`. This will inherently return all versions of that nuget package. Of course, it will not work for NuGet packages that does not have "nuget.id" defined, but that also means they are faulty and incorrectly created.

Do be aware, that if you have duplicates (package is hosted in multiple repositories) the list will contains these as well. But you can always sanitize the output afterwards.

I like to use JFrog CLI for interfacing with Artifactory as it takes care of credentials, but you can use the above curl command directly in curl too.